# Javascript elements selectting ordering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say i have a HTML like:

```
<div class='container'>
    <input class='first'>
    <input class='second'>
</div>
```

now if ill select the inputs:

```
var inputs = $('input');
```

can I be 100% sure that `inputs[0]` will be `<input class='first'>` and `inputs[1]` `<input class='second'>`?

If so is it only with jQuery? Can i use any element selecting method to have them sorted by occurrence in HTML code?

Comment: yes 101% lol, as it's a collection of elements and the index always starts from 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if your HTML does not have any other `input` element that appear before your current HTML.

No, because if your HTML look like this:

```
<input class='thisisfirst' />
<div class='container'>
    <input class='first'>
    <input class='second'>
</div>
```

Then `inputs[0]` will be the `input` with class `thisisfirst`. To make it more correctly that `inputs[0]` will be `<input class='first'>`, you can make your selector being more specific by targeting parent element of your `<input class='first'>` which is `.container`:

```
$('.container input:eq(0)');
```

Comment: Thank you, its 'Yes' then because I'm searching in a parent container :)

Answer (score 1):

You can. Actually there's a css selector (:first-child) that is relying on this